# Internet Explorer CSS display block issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, tabs

I'm trying to create a simple tab menu using a table and div blocks.
When a tab is clicked, the style of the tab changes to create the effect that the tabs were switched and the body, which is a div block inside a table cell, is switched for another div block using css (display:block and display:none). It works the way it's supposed to in firefox, but in IE 11 the tabs size are modified when they are switched.

Here is the page:
[Tab Example](http://tropicalfarm.byethost13.com/tabs/tabs.html)

```js
function tabClick(tab, bodyId) {

  // tabs and bodyes arrays
  var tabCol = [document.getElementById('tab1'), document.getElementById('tab2'), document.getElementById('tab3')];
  var bodyCol = [document.getElementById('body1'), document.getElementById('body2'), document.getElementById('body3')];

  for (var i = 0; i < tabCol.length; i++) {

    // find the tab that was clicke and
    // set it's status to selected. set
    // the others to unselected
    if (tab === tabCol[i]) {
      tabCol[i].className = 'tabSel';
    } else {
      tabCol[i].className = 'tabUnsel';
    }

    // show the body related to the selected
    // tab and hide the others
    if (bodyCol[i].id == bodyId) {
      bodyCol[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      bodyCol[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

  }

}
```

```css
.tabUnsel:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.tabUnsel {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: #898c95 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.tabSel {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: #898c95 solid 1px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 500px; font-family: verdana; font-size: 11px;" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: #898c95 solid 1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tab1" class="tabSel" onclick="tabClick(this,'body1');">Tab 1</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: #898c95 solid 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tab2" class="tabUnsel" onclick="tabClick(this,'body2');">Tab 2</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: #898c95 solid 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tab3" class="tabUnsel" onclick="tabClick(this,'body3');">Tab 3</td>
    <td style="width: 100%; border-bottom: #898c95 solid 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: #898c95 solid 1px; border-top: 0; padding: 10px;" colspan="7">
      <div id="body1" style="width:100%; min-height: 300px;">
        Tab 1 content
      </div>
      <div id="body2" style="width:100%; min-height: 300px; display: none;">
        Tab 2 content
        <br/>
        <img src="http://tropicalfarm.byethost13.com/tabs/img1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://tropicalfarm.byethost13.com/tabs/img2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="body3" style="width:100%; min-height: 300px; display: none;">
        Tab 3 content
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use IE to download Chrome or Firefox? That would be ideal ;)

Comment: Because I'm not creating a private website... there's a lot of people who still use IE and will eventually access my website... rite?! :/

Comment: I understand. Was being loyal to Chrome and Firefox who put day and night to give life to web. ;). I hope you would agree with me. Correct?

Comment: just use jQuery UI tabs - https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: The tabs also spread out in Chrome

Comment: I get the same issue in Chrome (assuming I'm understanding it correctly and the issue is to do with the tab size changing when switching between tabs 1 & 2)

Comment: `vertical-align: central` ? I have not seen that before

Comment: I think  `min-height` not working in IE. So this thing is happening.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't hard code the widths on the tabs and spacers? If not, it's easily do able

Comment: why you need to apply display:block just remove display:none ,Hope it will work

Comment: the issue is there for all browsers

Comment: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery - you can try this instead

Comment: @mplungjan - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-inline/#propdef-vertical-align see under ["alignment-baseline"](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-inline/#valdef-alignment-baseline-central)

Comment: @Alohci - supported by which browsers? I cannot find it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align or in caniuse

Comment: @mplungjan - As far as I know, no browsers currently support it. Of course, one could use it in a progressive enhancement way, so that it would be picked up when/if browsers do implement it.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your empty tap style for example

```
 empty-tap{
  min-height: 500px; 
   height:auto !important; 
   height: 500px;
}
```

the source [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/)

Comment: Which empty tab and when to know it is empty?

Comment: well in the question the style where inline style so i simply Suggest adding a class to the empty tab and about knowing when a tab is empty it depends on the way that will be used to fill the tabs (if they are dynamic) if not simply the class can be added manually. please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The tabs will be filled dynamically... there will be empty tabs, others with little content and others with a lot of content... and this is exactly what is causing the issue, the amount of content...

Comment: if the added the style in the answer to all the cells then all the empty cells will be 500 height and the cells with content will be take more height. if you want your empty tab to take as high as the tab with content you can use jquery to find it out